# how to find xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]Following is the HTML of the page, How do i get the Xpath or is there anyother way to automate using java?In fact, we shud click on this "continue" button.

```
 <regform-button>
<button ng-disabled="activityIndicator" ng-click="validate()" type="button">
<div template="api-loader" ng-http-loader="">
<div class="http-loader__wrapper ng-hide" ng-show="showLoader" ng-include="template">
<span class="api-loader"></span>
</div>
</div>
<ng-transclude>
</button>
</regform-button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Chrome, right click on the button, and select Inspect in the popup.  The html will open in a developer tools frame.  Right click on the element in the developer tools frame, hover over copy, select copy xpath.

Here is the XPath to the form on the URL.

//*[@id="main-frame"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/regform-steps/ng-transclude/regform-step[1]/ng-form/ng-transclude/regform-button/button

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://uk.match.com/unlogged/landing/2016/06/02/hpv-belowthefold-3steps-geo-psc-bowling?klid=6740");
    //fill in fields
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-frame\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/regform-steps/ng-transclude/regform-step[1]/ng-form/ng-transclude/regform-button/button"));
    element.click();
```

Comment: It dint work or me. it stays on the same page. it is supposed to go to the next step in next page.

Comment: Did you fill in the fields by hand or code?  I stepped through the code with a debuger and filled in the fields by hand.  Did the page simply not go anywhere on the click?  Did the page return with validation errors?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//regform-button/button")).click();
```

Comment: Dint work. Stays in the same page.Tried: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//regform-button/button")).click();

Comment: are you sure that's the `continue` button?

Comment: Yes. Infact trying to automate this registration form in the following link. https://uk.match.com/unlogged/landing/2016/06/02/hpv-belowthefold-3steps-geo-psc-bowling?klid=6740

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the console for Google Chrome and typing the following:
document.evaluate("//regform-button/button", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()

It works...that's if you've specified the required fields. Also be sure to wait for a while (2 secs to be sure) after specifying the required fields as there might be an additional load after setting the required fields.

Edit: The code is javascript..I just took the xpath given by the previous answers and used that to locate the element through js. I'm saying that "//regform-button/button" should work..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected the required values from the drop-downs appearing before **Continue** button, you can click on **Continue** button using the following statement:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Continue']")).click();
```

Comment: Is this for chrome or FF browser?

Comment: It should work for both Chrome and Firefox. I had tested it using Firefox and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath worked for me.But I dont know, why is it different for each different browser.

For Firefox :

```
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-frame']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/regform-steps/ng-transclude/regform-step[1]/ng-form/ng-transclude/regform-button/button")).click()`;
```

For chrome: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//regform-button/button")).click();`